# Solving a puzzle with Prolog, throws error "Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated"

Tags: prolog, clpfd

I'm trying to solve the following problem using logical constraints:

> The packer has to place 5 crates onto a long lorry. The 5 crates
> contain chickens, barley, foxes, rat poison and wheat. The crates need
> to be arranged in a long line without any gaps between them so that:
>
> • the chickens are separated from the foxes;
>
> • the rat poison is not next to the barley;
>
> • the rat poison is not next to the wheat.
>
> Find out
> how may different ways there are of arranging these crates subject to
> these packing constraints.

This is what I have so far:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

position(Crates) :-
   Crates = [Chicken, Barley, Foxes, RatPoison, Wheat],
   Regions ins 1..5,
   Chicken   #\= Foxes,
   RatPoison #\= Barley,
   RatPoison #\= Wheat,
   labeling([], Regions).
```

It throws the error "Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated" when I try to run it.

I'm very new to Prolog so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try `[Regions] ins 1..5` and `labeling([], [Regions]).` Read CLPFD documentation regarding `ins` and `labeling`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you are restricting `Regions` to `1..5` and than labeling it. But you want to know the possible positions for the 5 crates. So restrict and label `Crates`. Note that `Regions` is a free variable when you restrict it to values between 1 and 5 and the length of the list `Regions` is not restricted at all, thus the error when you try to label it. In this version, in the last goal of the predicate position/1, the list `Crates` is already restricted to a fixed length (=5) and to values between 1 and 5 when being labeled.

Then you want the chicken and the foxes to not be in the same crate: `Chicken #\= Foxes`. But according to the task description they are in different crates anyway. You rather want them to be not in adjacent crates. The same goes for ratpoison/barley and ratpoison/wheat. Also no two crates can be in the same position: you can use all_distinct/1 form library(clpfd) for that. Putting this all together you get something like:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

position(Crates) :-
    Crates = [Chicken, Barley, Foxes, RatPoison, Wheat],
    Crates ins 1..5,
    all_distinct(Crates),
    not_adjacent(Chicken,Foxes),
    not_adjacent(RatPoison,Barley),
    not_adjacent(RatPoison,Wheat),
    labeling([], Crates).

not_adjacent(X,Y) :-
    X #\= Y+1,
    Y #\= X+1.
```

Now try to query position/1:

```
   ?- position(Crates).
Crates = [1,2,4,5,3] ? ;
Crates = [1,3,4,5,2] ? ;
Crates = [1,4,3,2,5] ?
...
```

If you don't want to go through all solutions interactively you can use findall/3 and length/2 to show all solutions and to count them:

```
   ?- findall(Crates,position(Crates),L),length(L,X).
L = [[1,2,4,5,3],[1,3,4,5,2],[1,4,3,2,5],[1,5,3,2,4],[2,1,4,3,5],[2,1,4,5,3],[2,3,4,1,5],[2,3,4,5,1],[2,3,5,1,4],[2,4,5,1,3],[2,5,4,1,3],[2,5,4,3,1],[3,1,5,4,2],[3,2,5,4,1],[3,4,1,2,5],[3,5,1,2,4],[4,1,2,3,5],[4,1,2,5,3],[4,2,1,5,3],[4,3,1,5,2],[4,3,2,1,5],[4,3,2,5,1],[4,5,2,1,3],[4,5,2,3,1],[5,1,3,4,2],[5,2,3,4,1],[5,3,2,1,4],[5,4,2,1,3]],
X = 28
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that's extremely helpful!

Answer (score 1):

My model gives different result WRT @tas answer. Maybe I don't fully understand the phrase

> the chickens are separated from the foxes

that I translate like

```
abs(Chicken - Foxes) #> 2
```

Anyway, the full model

```
position(Crates) :-
    Crates = [Chicken, Barley, Foxes, RatPoison, Wheat],
    all_different(Crates),
    Crates ins 1..5,
    abs(Chicken - Foxes) #> 2,
    abs(RatPoison - Barley) #> 1,
    abs(RatPoison - Wheat) #> 1,
    label(Crates).
```

yields

```
?- aggregate(count,Cs^position(Cs),N).
N = 8.
```

Comment: If the Chicken are in crate 3 and the foxes are in crate 1 (e.g. [3,4,1,2,5]) they are clearly separated as the crates are "arranged in a long line" but `abs(Chicken - Foxes) #> 2` fails as 3-1=2. With `abs(Chicken - Foxes) #> 1` your version yields the same result as mine ;-)

Comment: sure, could be a 'linguistic trap'. I was not sure about the purpose to express it differently.

Comment: I feel that the problem statement is somewhat misleading, particularly when it comes to "foxes" and "chickens"... IMO there is exactly one fox and exactly one fox.